# Double Integral Range

Tags: integration

we want the **Surface** between the two equation:

- $r= 1 + \cos\theta$
- $r = 1$ (circle)

we can use a duble integral to solve this:

$$
S = \int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2} \int_1^{1+\cos\theta} r  \,dr\,d\theta
$$
the correct bound are what you see above, the question is;
please just explain clear why bounds occurs like this?

Comment: should the limits not be $0$ to $2 \pi$?

Comment: If you draw a picture, only for $\;\theta\in\left[-\frac\pi2,\,\frac\pi2\right]\;$ (meaning: the semiplane to the left of the $\;y\,-$ axis) there is a region "between" both curves. On the right semiplane the unit circle is wholly contained in the region enclosed by the cardiod-like curve.

Comment: clearly the limits come from the complete problem statement which has not been provided.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Mathematica to display the region

```
region = With[{r = Sqrt[x^2 + y^2], theta = ArcTan[x, y]}, 
   ImplicitRegion[-Pi/2 <= theta <= Pi/2 && 
     1 <= r <= 1 + Cos[theta] && -1 <= x <= 2 && -3/2 < y < 3/2, {x, y}]];

Show[
 RegionPlot[region],
 PolarPlot[{1, 1 + Cos[theta]}, {theta, -Pi, Pi},
  PlotLegends -> "Expressions",
  PlotStyle -> Thick],
 PlotRange -> {{-1.05, 2.05}, {-1.55, 1.55}},
 AspectRatio -> Automatic,
 Axes -> True]
```

[image]

The approximate area is

```
Area[DiscretizeRegion[region, AccuracyGoal -> 7, PrecisionGoal -> 7]]

(*  2.78539  *)
```

The exact area is

```
Integrate[r, {theta, -Pi/2, Pi/2}, {r, 1, 1 + Cos[theta]}]

(*  (8 + Pi)/4  *)

% // N

(*  2.7854  *)
```